# How to pass data to directive's isolate scope compiled using $compile

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive's scope defined like this:

```
app.directive('mine', function() {
    return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        data: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
        console.log('executing');
        console.log(scope.data);
    }
  }
});
```

Then I compile it:

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, $compile, $rootScope) {
  var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
  scope.data = 777;
  $compile(angular.element('<mine></mine>'))(scope);
});
```

And the directive doesn't receive the data. I've investigated the source code and it seems that it's because attributes are missing. Certainly I can add attributes, but this doesn't seem to be the right approach. Is there another way to use both `$compile` and defined isolate scope on the directive that is being compiled without specifying attributes?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/60/)

Comment: So you want both two-way binding and no binding at the same time ...

Comment: @zeroflagL, sorry, I don't undestand, can you please clarify? maybe take a look at the fiddle

Comment: @zeroflagL, `scope.data = 777;` is outside code. Please take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/60/)

Comment: @zeroflagL, there are two scopes, one is created by `$rootScope.new(true);` - 1, the other - 2, is created automatically by `angular` since I use `scope: {}` notation. I want to propagate the data from scope 1 to scope 2. What am I missing?

Comment: The directive's scope is isolated. You need `<mine data="data"></mine>` to propagate the value. What you try to do is to circumvent the isolation and the binding.

Comment: @zeroflagL, yeah, I know about the need to specify attributes. I'm wondering if there is another way to pass the value... it seems that there is not.